# Hibernate Russian Letters uppercase

Tags: java, hibernate, cyrillic

I'm trying to find substring in string using restrictions `ilike` and `MatchMode.ANYWHERE`, but it does not work with Russian letters in uppercase. In lower case all okay. Somebody knows what to do with it?

Code Example: `Criterion userLikeCriteria = Restrictions.like("username", username, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);`

Problem Example: I want to find word: "Москва" (Moscow) and enter a substring to find it: "М" (Russian letter M in uppercase) - and there are no result from database, but if i will enter any other letter except "М" as substring - i will find word "Москва". In the same time if word "Москва" wont contain uppercase letter М - "москва" (moscow), than i will find it when enter a search substring as "м" - Russian letter m in lowercase.

Comment: Did you try the same with HQL & native sql ? Hope you have appropriate charset for you DB ?

Comment: I did not try the same HQL or native sql because it will work, i'm sure. Problem not in charset, because lowercase russian letters are correctly.